# dataclasses.dataclass with __init_subclass__

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, python-dataclasses

My confusion is with the interplay between `dataclasses` & `__init_subclass__`.

I am trying to implement a base class that will exclusively be inherited from. In this example, `A` is the base class. It is my understanding from reading the python docs on [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) that simply adding a decorator should automatically create some special dunder methods for me. Quoting their docs:

---

> For example, this code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def total_cost(self) -> float:
        return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
```

> will add, among other things, a `__init__()` that looks like:

```
def __init__(self, name: str, unit_price: float, quantity_on_hand: int = 0):
    self.name = name
    self.unit_price = unit_price
    self.quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand
```

---

This is an instance variable, no? From the classes [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), it shows a toy example, which reads super clear.

```
class Dog:

    kind = 'canine'         # class variable shared by all instances

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name    # instance variable unique to each instance
```

A main gap in my understanding is - is it an instance variable or a class variable? From my testing below, it is a class variable, but from the docs, it shows an instance variable as it's proximal implementation. It may be that most of my problem is there. I've also read the python docs on [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), which do not go into `dataclasses`.

---

The problem continues with the seemingly limited docs on [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init_subclass__#customizing-class-creation), which yields another gap in my understanding. I am also making use of `__init_subclass__`, in order to enforce that my subclasses have indeed instantiated the variable `x`.

Below, we have `A`, which has an instance variable `x` set to None. `B`, `C`, and `D` all subclass `A`, in different ways (hoping) to determine implementation specifics.

`B` inherits from `A`, setting a class variable of `x`.
`D` is a dataclass, which inherits from `A`, setting what would appear to be a class variable of `x`. However, given their docs from above, it seems that the class variable `x` of `D` should be created as an instance variable. Thus, when `D` is created, it should first call `__init_subclass__`, in that function, it will check to see if `x` exists in `D` - by my understanding, it *should* not; however, the code passes scot-free. I believe `D()` will create `x` as an instance variable because the dataclass [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) show that this will create an `__init__` for the user.

> "will add, among other things..." <insert `__init__ code`>

I must be wrong here but I'm struggling to put it together.

```
import dataclasses

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if not getattr(cls, 'x') or not cls.x:
            raise TypeError(
                f'Cannot instantiate {cls.__name__}, as all subclasses of {cls.__base__.__name__} must set x.'
            )


class B(A):
    x = 'instantiated-in-b'


@dataclasses.dataclass
class D(A):
    x : str = 'instantiated-in-d'



class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'instantiated-in-c'


print('B', B())
print('D', D())
print('C', C())
```

The code, per my expectation, properly fails with `C()`. Executing the above code will succeed with `D`, which does not compute for me. In my understanding (which is wrong), I am defining a `field`, which means that `dataclass` should expand my class variables as instance variables. (The previous statement is most probably where I am wrong, but I cannot find anything that documents this behavior. Are data classes not actually expanding class variables as instance variables? It certainly appears that way from the visual explanation in their docs.) From the dataclass [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass):

> The dataclass() decorator examines the class to find fields. A field is defined as a class variable that has a type annotation.

---

Thus - **why** - when creating an instance `D()` - does it slide past the `__init_subclass__` of its parent `A`?

Apologies for the lengthy post, I must be missing something simple, so if once can point me in the right direction, that would be excellent. TIA!

---

I have just found the [implementation for dataclasses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/dataclasses.py) from the CPython github.

Related Articles:

- [Understanding __init_subclass__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400284/understanding-init-subclass)
- [python-why-use-self-in-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475871/python-why-use-self-in-a-class)
- [proper-way-to-create-class-variable-in-data-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109087/how-to-get-instance-variables-in-python)
- [how-to-get-instance-variables-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937520/proper-way-to-create-class-variable-in-data-class)
- [enforcing-class-variables-in-a-subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046369/enforcing-class-variables-in-a-subclass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init_subclass__` is called when initializing a subclass. *Not* when initializing an *instance* of a subclass - it's called when initializing the *subclass itself*. Your exception occurs while trying to create the `C` class, not while trying to evaluate `C()`.

Decorators, such as `@dataclass`, are a post-processing mechanism, not a pre-processing mechanism. A class decorator takes an existing class that has already gone through all the standard initialization, including `__init_subclass__`, and modifies the class. Since this happens after `__init_subclass__`, `__init_subclass__` doesn't see any of the modifications that `@dataclass` performs.

Even if the decorator were to be applied first, `D` still would have passed the check in `A.__init_subclass__`, because the dataclass decorator will set `D.x` to the default value of the `x` field anyway, so `__init_subclass__` will find a value of `x`. In this case, that happens to be the same thing you set `D.x` to in the original class definition, but it can be a different object in cases where you construct `field` objects explicitly.

(Also, you probably wanted to write `hasattr` instead of `getattr` in `not getattr(cls, 'x')`.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Much more clear now. The only part I'm unsure on is the end, where you're saying that `D` would have passed the check because the data class will set `D.x` to the default value of the `x` field anyway. Are you saying that generally, when data classes are created, they instantiate [class/instance] variables as the default of the parent class? (It seems so!)

Comment: @spen.smith: I'm not sure what you mean, particularly the "default of the parent class" part. The default isn't coming from a parent class.

Comment: I’m meaning where you said “will set `D.x` to in the original class definition”. I am using “parent” as my understanding of your use of “original”